# carry (cache?) web elements over to new pages as they load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Wondering if there's a way to animate a div containing an image while a new page loads behind the animation (probably using jQuery, but not sure if there's an easier way).

There's an "Enter" button, and I'm hoping to move the company's logo to rest in a new position once the enter button is pressed and the main landing page loads during the animation.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you edit your post to make clear what the question is (including the title). Maybe something like: how to display a loading image while the page is being loaded? Don't forget to mention what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for would be jQuery's `animate()` function. Since you didn't include any source, take a look at what I placed below and see if you can rework it to your use. Also, regarding "carrying" over content, you could use another `<div />` and replace the `.html()` contents with the results of the search, or perhaps using an [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) so the user isn't leaving the page.

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
  $('#theLogo').animate({
    left: '+=120'
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theLogo">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="Google">
</div>
<button type="button">Move it</button>
```